# How to create dynamic buttons based on an arraylist

Tags: c#, loops, arraylist, foreach

I'm having some trouble creating a foreach loop that creates buttons dynamically based on a List that is inside the NamesDA class.

I'm getting errors such as: Cannot convert type 'Program1.Names' to 'int'. I've tried what I know to fix the conversion error, but I don't know the correct way to do it.

**Edit 1:** allNames is an array list inside NamesDA that reads a csv file.
It returns a list of strings and int's, which then they are to be used to create the buttons and represent them.

**Edit 2:** The foreach loop problem is solved now, but I'm unable to get the values of column[0] for button text and column[1] for button tag.

The NamesDA class:

```
private const string path = "names.csv";
public static List<Names> GetNames()
{
   StreamReader textIn = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read));
   List<Names> allNames = new List<Names>();
   while (textIn.Peek() != -1)
   {
       string row = textIn.ReadLine();
       string[] columns = row.Split(',');
       allNames.Add(new Names(columns[0].ToString(), Convert.ToInt16(columns[1])));
   }

   textIn.Close();
   return allNames;
}
```

The form:

```
int startTop = 20;
int startLeft = 17;

allNames = NamesDA.GetNames(); //calling the method in the NamesDA class
foreach (int x in allNames) {
    names[x] = new Button();
    tempButton.Text = ""; //based on the list column[0]
    tempButton.Tag = "";  //based on the list column[1]
    names[x].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(startTop + (x * 95), startLeft);    
    listView.Controls.Add(names[x]);
}
```

Comment: what type does `NamesDA.GetNames()` return? what type is `all`?

Comment: You are assigning `names[x]`, but you are adding `allNames[x]`.

Comment: There are few variable that are undefined in the given snippet(`names`, `all`) could you please define them?

Comment: You need to include all your code. You're missing important parts.

Comment: How is the record NAMES defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Updates it is clear that `allNames` is a `List<Names>`, where `Names` is a class contains two properties/fields one is of type int(let it be `_id`) and the another one is of type string(let it be `_name`). So you have to re create the loop as like the following:

Updates : You can Set the button location as well, if you need that you have to define two integer properties in the class(let it be `int positionX=10` and `int PositionY=30`) Now take a look at the updated code:

```
int nextLeft=30;

foreach (Names name in allNames) 
{
    Button tempButton = new Button();    
    tempButton.Name = name._id;
    tempButton.Text = name._name;
    tempButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(name.positionX + nextLeft,name.positionY);
    listView.Controls.Add(tempButton);
    nextLeft+=30;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how I might be able to set the location as well? btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(startTop + (x * 95), startLeft); its say's operator * cannot be applied to operands of type Names and 'int'

Comment: For some reason it keeps telling me: 'Names' does not contain a definition for 'startTop' and no extension method 'startTop' accepting a first argument of type Names' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Take a look at the snippet that i have given, There is nothing named `startTop`